# Forms for polymorphic associations that are displayed in the same view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models: `Post,` `Reply` and `Vote`. `Vote` as a polymorphic association with `Post` and `Reply`:

**routes.rb:**

```
   resources :posts do
    resources :votes
    resources :replies do
      resources :votes
    end
  end
  resources :votes,         only: [:create, :destroy]
```

**votes_controller.rb:**

```
  def create
    @votable = find_votable
    @vote = @votable.votes.create(params[:vote])
    if @votable.save
     # vote saved
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def find_votable
    params.each do |name, value|
      if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
        return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
      end
    end
    nil
  end
```

**posts_controller.rb:**

```
def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @replies = @post.replies.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @reply = @post.replies.build
    @votable = ? # not sure what to add here
    @vote = Vote.new
 end
```

**posts/show.erb:**

```
  <%= form_for ([@votable, @vote]) do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :polarity %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :polarity %>
      <%= f.label :user_id %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :user_id %>
    </p>
    <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
  <% end %>

  <%= render 'replies/form' %>
```

**replies/form.rb:**

```
  <%= form_for ([@votable, @vote]) do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :polarity %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :polarity %>
      <%= f.label :user_id %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :user_id %>
    </p>
    <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
  <% end %>
```

I'm not sure how to define `@votable` in the post controller so it does `Post.find(params[:id])` for the post's vote form and `Reply.find(params[:id])` for vote's post form. This is hard since both `posts` and `replies` are in the same show view.

Is there any workaround? (Or is there a better approach? Like making the `@votable` variable in the votes controller, available in the post controller?)

Comment: How did you solve this in the end? Having exactly the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

What your trying to is called nested forms. The relations being polymorphic should not affect how to implement it. Try watching the railscast bellow

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

and check this gem out

https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

its old so there might be newer gems and approaches to this.

Comment: Actually, I need Rails to figure out when `votable` is a `post` and when it is a `reply` in the post's show view.